# Flutter show dialog from accessibility service

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I was working on a flutter app where a dialog box will be shown whenever power button os pressed I was able to override powerbutton but dont have an idea of how to show a dialogbox even when the app is closed.

I tried to start flutter engine from the service but resulted in a error I want the app to be function more like a volume panel app avaiable for android

Answer (score 1):

You can use Android's accessibility service to receive callbacks in your app.
Even if the app is closed, it can start the app and do whatever you want, in your case show a dialog.

Recently I needed a similar functionality in a Flutter app, where I needed to start the app on a long press of volume up button. And I did it using the accessibility service.

Though there are some plugins available for Flutter that provide accessibility service implementations, but I haven't found any library that provides these physical button-press action callbacks. I had to customize a library and add the function in native part.

Here is an official request to the developer of the most mature library available there: https://github.com/X-SLAYER/flutter_accessibility_service/issues/19

Here is the link to android accessibility service: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/service#methods

And I used the `protected boolean onKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) { throw new RuntimeException("Stub!"); }` method in the service implementation to get the callbacks.

Answer (score -1):

Implementing a feature to show a dialog box when the power button is pressed, especially when the Flutter app is not actively running, cannot be achieved purely with Flutter. Flutter is excellent for front-end app development, but it has limitations when it comes to deep system-level interactions, particularly when the app is not in the foreground
Interacting with system hardware buttons like the power button, especially when the app is closed, requires native Android or iOS code.

To implement this feature, you will need to integrate Flutter with native Android code:

1. Native Android Service: Create a background service using Kotlin or Java that listens for the power button press.
2. Broadcast Receiver: Implement a broadcast receiver to detect the power button event.
3. Dialog Box Display: Use native Android UI components to display the dialog box.
4. Flutter Integration (if needed): Communicate between the native code and Flutter using method channels if you need to send data back to the Flutter app when it's running.
5. Handle Permissions and Security: Ensure appropriate permissions are requested, and handle any security concerns.